# Can't refer to json data with D3 js if it has a whitespace

Tags: javascript, d3.js, whitespace, space

I got a JSON file with value's that got a whitespace in them. like so:

```
"Project 3":6
```

I If try to do something in D3.js with the data like so

```
var meanProject3 = d3.mean(data, function(d) {return d.project 3 });
console.log(meanProject3);
```

i got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

If i try it with nodes that don't have whitespace it works fine.
I can't edit the json file. Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dot notation when the property name has special characters such as white space. Try:

```
return d['Project 3']
```

Note that property names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bracket notation in this case, see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MUh6g/)

```
var test = {
    "Project 3":"found it"
};

alert(test["Project 3"]);
```